# Latex: \lneq displaying as \nleq

Tags: math-mode, symbols

The problem i have is that both

`\lneq` and `\nleq`

display as the same symbol with different sizes.

I only need the "equality bar" below `<` to be crossed out. Instead the whole symbol is crossed in both cases.

Comment: [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) suggest you include [`amssymb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb). Did you try it? See http://i.stack.imgur.com/by8gv.png

Comment: thanks for your comment. it made me realize the problem; I first include amssymb and later on mnsymb. the latter overwrites nleq.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by Werner above made me realize that i load both `amssymb` and `mnsymb`. The latter does not distinguish `\nleq` and `\lneq`.